# How to access the html component from a composite component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this component

```
var React = require("react");

var Input = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (<input {...this.props}/>)
  }
})

module.exports = Input;
```

This is another component which uses the first component

```
var React = require('react');
var Button = require('./Button.react');
var Input = require('./Input.react');

var Form = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return( <div>
        <Input ref = {(input) => this._user=input} placeholder='Username'/>
        <Input ref = {(input) => this._pass=input} type="password" placeholder='Password'/>
        <Button onClick={this.onPress}>Login</Button>
    </div> )
  },
  onPress:function(){
    console.log(this._user.value);
  }
});

module.exports = Form;
```

I want to access the value property of the `<input />` of the first component. I understand that only the component constructor is available in the callback function provided for ref attribute.

So is there any way I can access the html component within the second component ?

I apologise if this question is duplicate , I am new to react and  unfamiliar with the terminology.

Comment: `callbacks` might help you

Comment: @TheReason could you ellaborate

Comment: @Abhishek what's your use case? If the parent needs to access the child in most cases that's bad design. I have found myself asking the same question and then finding better solution

Comment: @leo I want to access the <input placeholder='Username'/> element within the Form component. I guess i could use ReactDOM.findDOMNode but is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: you were almost there - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

```
<Input ref = {(input) => this._pass=input} type="password" placeholder='Password'/>
```

and then

```
this._pass.yourValueFunction()
```

---

However, I suspect this is not what you want to do. You're trying to get the value from `<Input />`, but that should be done with `onChange` callback from `<Input />` that's setting the value in its parent.

Something like...

```
var Input = React.createClass({
   render() {
    return <input {...this.props} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
   }
})
```

and in your parent you need to define handleChange callback, for example

```
handleChange(e) { 
  this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })
  // or possibly this.inputValue = inputValue
}
```

and pass it to the `<Input />`

```
<Input handleChange={handleChange} ... />
```

Then the `<Input />` value will always be accessible: `this.state.inputValue`

Comment: @Abhishek have in mind that's the React way, not a workaround. I strongly recommend you to read this - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html
happy coding;-)

Comment: upon a closer look , i found that the component is being rendered every time we type something into the input field , are you sure this is the way to do it ?

Comment: yes, absolutely, because you set state. you can also use this.inputValue = inputValue if you want to avoid rerender

Comment: I apologise , but I don't see how rendering a component multiple times is optimal , are you certain this is the way?

Comment: the function render() is called, but it doesn't mean that react changes anything. In fact, it doesn't if your markup doesn't depend on this.state.inputValue. But if it really doesn't depend on this.state.inputValue, this.inputValue = inputValue is better than this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value }) because render() wouldnt be called.

Comment: see, I edited the handleChange(e) in my answer. Good point, btw!